# sched_clock() usage in linux kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, scheduler

I would like to know is there any caveats in using sched_clock()? Any case when it is not safe to use? And is it okay if I use it very early in kernel.bootup?

Btw the Linux runs on ARM platform

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add timestamp support for a code piece that gets executed early at boot. The problem once i call sched_clock() the system hangs and it goes haywire with dmesg garbled etc. When i try to replace sched_clock() by the default implemented calculated just using jiffies or i just assign timestamp as zero, then its working fine

Comment: It is unlikely to work before interrupts are setup.  In early boot, there are many issues with memory.  Specifically, the vector table needs to be setup so that every process can see it.  Some controllers may need a clock and other features before interrupts can be serviced.  So, it is unlikely that `sched_clock()` will work.  You could code your own functions which would read a timer register that was setup by some boot code.  Take care as the MMU is probably also being setup and changing here.

Comment: *"I am trying to add timestamp support..."* -- Either look at how the kernel logger generates timestamps, or simply output to the logger (with the timestamp option enabled of course).